# Why are the Fermi levels of two different superconductors in a Josephson junction the same?

Tags: superconductivity, josephson-junction

[ELECTRON TUNNELING AND SUPERCONDUCTIVITY](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1973/giaever-lecture.pdf) (Fig. 10A)–
This is Giaever's Nobel lecture about how to measure the energy gap of each superconductor using a Josephson junction. I wonder why we can assume that the Fermi levels of the two different superconductors in a Josephson junction are the same (when the bias voltage is zero). Thank you.